# Prevent users from uploading files when they are on external networks

Tags: windows, security, powershell, group-policy, task-scheduler

Is there a way to prevent users from uploading files when they are on external networks? The reason for this is internal security and protection of company confidential documents. They should be able to access our VPN services, and then they could access the internet using our Firewall rules. Is there a way to do this without any third-party MDS software? I am thinking GPO policy, PowerShell with Task Scheduler and other Windows tools and services.

Comment: `uploading files` could be many different things.

Comment: **Is there a way to prevent users from uploading files when they are on external networks?** - From where? To where?

Comment: @joeqwerty From their laptops to anywhere else. SMB sharing to their home computers, uploading to network drives, sharing on the internet, sending via email....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure a [Always On VPN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-access/vpn/always-on-vpn/always-on-vpn-technology-overview) on your VPN server. With this you will be able to force users to connect to internet thru your network with your firewall rules.

Answer (score 2):

Configuring [conditional access](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/overview) would be the golden bullet. I linked to the Azure documentation, but on premise you could reach the same by configuring your firewall, allowing all the internal networks, except the VPN services.

Comment: Thank you for this link. I will probably be some conditional firewall configuration, but I don't know how to trigger firewall config change.